# Sonar: Move constants to a class or enum

Tags: java, spring

I found one project on Internet and after I downloaded it, I got this message from `SonarQube`:

> Move constants to a class or enum.

But, when I downloaded `SonarLint`, it did not report any code smell.

This is the code:

```
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {

    String QUERY = "update Task t set t.isDeleted = true where t.id = :taskId";

    @Modifying
    @Query(QUERY)
    void deleteTaskById(@Param(value = "taskId") long taskId);
}
```

My question is: **Should I remove constant `QUERY` and write it directly into `@Query` or I can leave it like this?**

**Note:** This is a short query and it can easily be put inside `@Query`. But I am also interested what would be the best practice if this query was longer(ex. if it had 300 characters or more).

Comment: The code provided isn't yours?

Comment: This reads like a Stack Overflow question.  You have a specific problem with which you want help.  Not a Code Review post where you are interested in any improvements to a section of code which you wrote.  At minimum, I would suggest trying to remove QUERY.  Because I don't think that's even your problem.  QUERY is not a constant.  It's a variable.  The two constants in that code are "taskId" and "update Task t set t.isDeleted = true where t.id = :taskId".  I would think that it is complaining about "taskId", as that looks like the kind of thing that could be stored as an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I do not see the reason why this needs to be a variable in the first place. If I were you I would either move this into the `@Query` annotation or better yet I would create a `@NamedQuery` under your `Task` entity class.

Also on a side note, I would avoid naming the repository method `deleteTaskById` as this name implies that a matching object will be deleted from the database. Since this is not the case here, I would rename the method to `markTaskAsDeleted` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I agree with you.
But, can you tell me what would you do if query was not short as this one(for example if it had 200 characters or more)?

Comment: It depends on your use case. If this concerns static queries (i.e ones that do not change dynamically) I would have them all organized under their entity class as named queries. Otherwise, I would look into using the `Criteria` API.